# Docker on Windows 10 with mobylinuxvm, how to add network interface/switch to a machine

Tags: windows, docker, networking

I am forced to use a Windows 10 Enterprise with a docker stack. What I want to achieve is, having a Linux machine running on it, with 2 network interfaces. One in my local LAN, and one NATted to the company VPN.

The NATted NIC with the company VPN is working out-of-the-box, but the other interface does not collaborate.

I bought a new USB network adapter, which is perfectly-recognized under Win10, I made it to get it running in the mobylinuxvm.ps1 in the docker-machine under the Hyper-V-Manager, but what now? I assume I have to do some 'docker network create .. ' but which driver to use and what type of network should it be? I expected it to be a "transparent" driver, but this one seems not available when docker runs in "Linux mode" what it does.

Then, my local LAN is 192.168.1.0/24, the LAN gateway is 192.168.1.1, the USB Adapter gets a DHCP address like 192.168.1.105, what would I have to set in the network settings for the docker network?

From the docker's point of view, what is the gateway for a docker VM (controlled by mobylinuxvm)? Should I create the network settings like `--subnet 192.168.1.0/24 --gateway 192.168.1.1 --ip-range 192.168.1.0/24` or should the gateway be `192.168.1.105` (the USB network adapter)?

I am 100% lost at the moment, I read a lot about using the macvlan driver with MAC spoofing, others use transparent driver which is obviously not working here...

Finally, when creating the network (docker network create ..) I had to ensure that the network is "external" and bound to the (in this case) "Ethernet 3" Adapter, or do I have to bind the network to the created Hyper-V Switch (DockerExt I called it) which is bound into the MobyLinuxVM?

The wired thing is, when I start a VM with the superseded docker-machine (which clearly creates a Hyper-V virtualized boot2docker Linux), I can easily bind the (external) Hyper-V Switch (on USB NIC) and the connection to my local LAN is perfectly working, but not ANY other network connection in any Company VPN or something.

If you arrived here, I really appreciate that you took the time reading until here. If you'd come up with an idea or hint, I would the really thankful!

best regards, a lost victim of Docker on Windows

Answer (score 1):

just made it, to whom it may concern :

The final missing part was to run the machine in the host network and to manually add an IP inside the VM.

What I did :

`docker run -ti --privileged --hostname stargate --name stargate --network host stargate:1`

Like this the container started, but had no IP on eth1

The vEthernet Adapter which I created (DockerExt) has the 192.168.1.11 assigned, and inside the container, I also added it like

`ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.11`

and immediately had connection to my other local network. The eth0 is still attached to the NAT because I still have connection into company network.

I think I will add another script to the ubuntu (stargate) which after boot adds the ip to the interface, so that I dont have to do that manually every morning ..